# Xcode 13 won't stay paused at breakpoint

Tags: xcode, xcode13, swift-pythonkit

I'm on Xcode 13 GM (13A233) and I'm noticing that it won't stay paused when it hits a breakpoint. It stops, but about a minute later it just resumes. Is there a new default setting that might cause this? I don't see anything relevant in "Behaviors," but maybe I'm missing something. Has anybody else encountered this issue?

The only unusual thing about my project is that I am calling Python from it, using PythonKit. But this breakpoint pause issue isn't isolated to code involving PythonKit.

I've tried all the usual "fixes"—i.e., clean build, delete derived data, reboot, etc. The app is just a simple SwiftUI app for macOS.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually the debugger crashing and the app detaching: `The LLDB RPC server has crashed. You may need to manually terminate your process. The crash log is located in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports and has a prefix 'lldb-rpc-server'. Please file a bug and attach the most recent crash log....`

It doesn't do it my main View, but does do it in a static method called on a singleton *in the app*, and also at various points in a custom package I'm developing alongside the app.

I see a similar unresolved issue from August at bugs.swift.org: [https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-15110?jql=text%20~%20%22lldb%20crash%22](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-15110?jql=text%20%7E%20%22lldb%20crash%22), In case anyone else is seeing the same issue (maybe you can post your log there).

UPDATE: I completely forgot that I was running on a dev snapshot toolchain. All good in Xcode 13.1 with bundled toolchain. Moral of the story; if something *really* strange is going on, check your toolchain.